# Send email via ajax once radio button is clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, email, radio-button

I am trying to send an email when someone clicks a radio button without having the page refresh. I've gotten the system to send emails with the value, it just refreshes everytime which I don't want. I am not the best with Ajax and Javascript, but any help would be much appreciated.

I've tried the `e.preventDefault();` function as well but can't seem to get that to work either.

I'm running the site via a localhost on the WordPress platform. Below is the code I have:

**PHP file for sending the email**

```
if(isset($_POST['radio'])){
 $user_info = get_userdata(1);
 $email = $user_info->user_email;
 $to = "example@example.com";
 $from = "donotreply@example.org"; 
 $subject = "Subject";
 $message = "Option Clicked: " . $_POST['radio'] . "\nName: " . 
 $user_info->last_name .  ", " . $user_info->first_name . "\nUser Email: ". $email;
 $headers = "From:" . $from;    
    wp_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="contact" action="unsubscribe.php" method="post" name="contact">
 <span class="close-button">&times;</span>
 <h3>Title</h3>
 <p>Description</p>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" id="option1" value="Option 1" /><label for="option1">Option 1</label>
   <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
  <li>
   <input type="radio" name="radio" id="option2" value="Option 2" /><label for="option2">Option 2</label>
   <div class="check"></div>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <div id="button" class="hide">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url($action['url']); ?>" class="unsubscribe-button button cancel">Submit and Cancel Subscription</a>
 </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('input[name$="radio"]').on('click', function(){
    var radio = $(this).val();
      $("#" + radio);
      $('#contact').on('submit', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'unsubscribe.php',
            data: {radio: radio},
            success: function() {
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
      });
});
```

Comment: remove `action="unsubscribe.php"` from html `<form>` tag

Comment: also,  remove `href="<?php echo esc_url($action['url']); ?>"` from html `<a>` tag. instead use `href='#'` and in the js use `e.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0):

You should not send the form in a context of an ajax call, so you have to remove the form's action and method.

Because actually, this action is called once the ajax's success callback is reached, so your page is refreshed.